# the requrement to establish web servers for load balance?

Tags: iis, web-server, load-balancing, windows-server-2016

I did search some topics such as [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/262400/redundant-load-balancers-for-windows-based-web-servers) and [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/329880/load-balancing-for-web-and-database-servers).

However, I'm a newbie in web server and believe that these information could not answer my doubts precisely.

Here's the situation. I'm trying to create a lab to do POC for future production environment which involve web server pool and network load balancer.

I will create some VMs of WinServer 2016 into a web server pool to demonstrate a website(lab_testsite.local) and apply third-party load balance solution on it, and would like to know:

1. do the web server need to have same web content to avoid errors for the web load balancing?
2. is there any required setups on IIS on each web server for web load balancing?
3. the website shall always be synced across all the web servers in the pool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. do the web server need to have same web content to avoid errors for the web load balancing?

It probably should, web servers will forward traffic in load balanced fashion, most likely you want all of them to be serving the same content. Otherwise (of course depending on the load balancing method) different clients/connections would get web pages with different content.

2. is there any required setups on IIS on each web server for web load balancing?

No, That being said, there is a NLB for windows servers, you might want to have a look at that, it provides HA and LB: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/network-load-balancing

And lastly, from a technical point you don't need to have the same content in your load balanced web sites. But in real world scenarios, you would like to load balance web sites with the same content. So if your website is keeping a state, then you would like that state to be shared among the webservers.